# Manage files with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am a new programmer using node.js. I want to manage files between a server and a client using Android. I have discovered that for this, actually, there is a replacement for `fs` which name is `graceful-fs`. But what draws my attention is that the NPM official website says that you need to write `fs.readFileSync('some-file-or-whatever');` to use it. What does this line mean? Does it mean that this only works with synchronous functions or something like that, or it is the same as `fs` module but just with some improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The `graceful-fs` module supports both synchronous and asynchronous versions of the function. It is a drop-in replacement for the built-in `fs` module so it has to implement its entire API.

See this file in the unit tests of this project for an example of `readFile` (not `readFileSync`) usage:

- https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/blob/master/test/readfile.js#L36

The differences between `fs` and `graceful-fs` are explained well on:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs
- https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

The API of the `fs` module is documented on:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I read that in the official web site and I didn't know what I could do. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @F.Riggio I'm glad it helped you. You can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that other people could see that your question is answered in searches.